# Compose two SVG files in python

Tags: python, svg

I would like to compose two SVG files (say a.svg and b.svg) in python in a very simple way: b.svg should be centered vertically and horizontally over a.svg

What is the easiest way to achieve that? I've seen libraries like svgwrite and svg_stack but I don't think they do what I want.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). It's a powerful image library with a friendly learning curve.